# How to assign an specific letter to an specific partition under Wine

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, wine

I use Lubuntu 15.04 and I have an internal hard disk drive with two partitions:

first partition to all the Lubuntu system and all the software I have.

Second partition to all my data (documents, music, videos, etc. etc. etc.).

I need to use a software made to Windows. The software runs perfectly with Lubuntu, under Wine, of course.

The only one problem I have is that the software uses a "profile" bank (to read the multimedia database) made under Windows, and all the files and folders references were made to the Windows drive "D:".

How can I tell to this software (under Wine) that the second partition of the HDD is the Drive "D:"? Can I? ???

Answer (score 0):

You can, by running `winecfg`:

[image]

Go the `Drives` tab:

[image]

Click <kbd>Add...</kbd>:

[image]

Select your drive letter, press <kbd>Ok</kbd>, then enter the path where the target drive is mounted in Ubuntu. For example, my common partition is mounted on `/home/muru/Downloads`:

[image]

Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>. Done.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It was  easier than I thought. Now all it runs OK!!! Thank you so much, buddy!!!